# Cmake - Could NOT find Boost windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake

Hej, I have a problem running my project with Cmake.
But I am getting an error.

```
"Could NOT find Boost"
```

I have the boost folder in

```
"C:\Program Fileenter code heres\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost"
```

images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhDBd.jpg

At first I got a error popup:

```
"error in configuration process, projekt files may be invalid"
```

Than I get this error.

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1  
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1  
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe     
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works  
Detecting C compiler ABI info  
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done  
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe   
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works  
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info   
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done     
Detecting CXX compile features     
Detecting CXX compile features - done      
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)       
Found eigen: C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/3rdParty/Eigen/include     
Looking for pthread.h      
Looking for pthread.h - not found    
Found Threads: TRUE      
Could NOT find Boost         
CMake Error at

C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:39 (message):
  common is required but boost was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:354 (pcl_report_not_found)
  C:/Program Files/PCL 1.6.0/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:500 (find_external_library)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "//mac/Home/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/openni_range_image_visualization/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "//mac/Home/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/openni_range_image_visualization/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

my `CMakeLists` contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(openni_range_image_visualization)

find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (openni_range_image_visualization openni_range_image_visualization.cpp)
target_link_libraries (openni_range_image_visualization ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Prior to  that  error it says `Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) ` - perhpas there is a mistake in your cmake file which is hard to guess at

Comment: I have updated the question with what my CMakeLists contains. I have pcl 1.6.0 and `CmakeLists` says : `find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)` do you think that's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050193/cmake-unable-to-find-boost

Comment: That's a coincidence. Anyhow i deleted `find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)` from `CMakeLists` and it compiled [http://i.imgur.com/JoM2b3N.png](Image from Cmake).. but now iam getting `name followed by "::" must be a class or namespace name` problem from visual strudio

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a few years back, but for anybody that is still running into this problem-- the default download instructions on the PCL website help install PCL 1.6.0, which is an old version of PCL that has this little "bug" with regards to boost.

Instead, head over to their Github page and download the latest release here:

https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases

for this bug has been fixed in the later releases.